# why my static file is not loading in django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

I paste a pdf file in my static folder and the file is not getting loaded. name of the file is np.pdf. previously I had resume.pdf and it was working fine. but after trying np.pdf(which is not working) i edited the code to resume.pdf again but when i'm clicking the resume link- the browser opens a pdf download pop up. again i edited to np.pdf- run the server again- not showing any error again a pop up of resume.pdf's download.
notes: I am new to django.

**html code**:

```
<a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% static 'np.pdf' %}">Resume</a>
```

Comment: Your code looks ok, but if your browser is downloading the PDF it is possibly related to the server configuration with mime type for this kind of resource.

Comment: Try running collect static after changing the name of the pdf.

Comment: are you running django in `DEBUG = True` mode?

Comment: @ruddra yes i am

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `{% load static %}` at the very beginning of your html page?

```
{% load static %}

<a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% static 'np.pdf' %}">Resume</a>
```

Comment: hey @caleb! thanks for replying! this is my code from home.html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <meta charset="utf-8">